# question about a divergant series does not make sense

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I saw a picture in my textbook. I didn't read anything about it, but I got an idea. see :https://i.stack.imgur.com/anf8N.jpg

Let the square's side be L :
$$
\begin{align}
&S_1=\left(\frac{L}{3}\right)^{2}\\
&S_2=\left(\frac{L}{3}\right)^{2} + 9\left(\frac{L}{3^2}\right)^{2}\\
&S_3=\left(\frac{L}{3}\right)^{2} + 9\left(\frac{L}{3^2}\right)^{2} + 9^2\left(\frac{L}{3^3}\right)^{2}\\
&S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} 9^{k-1}\left(\frac{L}{3^k}\right)^{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

I wish until now I am correct.

So, the infinite sum should be convergent to some value less or equal L^2
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 9^{k-1}\left(\frac{L}{3^k}\right)^{2} \leq  L^2\\
&\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 9^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{3^k}\right)^{2} \leq  1\\
\end{align}
$$

It does not make any sense to be divergenet, but it does.
see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_n%3D1%5Einfinity+9%5E%28n-1%29*%28L%2F3%5En%29%5E2

Lastly,I am just a student. I am expecting that there is something wrong in my work. That's why I am here.

Thanks.

Comment: The first part looks right since the drawing indeed show that each smaller square's side's length is one third the bigger one's, but your comment at the end of your calculations baffles me: what has to do that series in WA with the ones your dealing with in your question? Oh, and there 8 little squares, not 9...but this doesn't affect convergence.

Comment: The link is broken. It's the same series, WA shows that it's divergent. Anyway, Harold just solved it. Thanks

Comment: @user98456 This is called the [Sierpinski carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note there are not 9, but 8 new squares.

Comment: Yes!!, Now it makes perfect sense. It converges to L^2. Thanks a lot. Never though the mistake would be that obvious. God!,I am so stupid.

Comment: @user98456, no you aren't. Should see some of _my_ blunders... just drink your morning coffee ;-)

Comment: That's a pretty good attention exercise, in fact. :)